# how to handle webhook responses sent through API in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am using an API to post request, and i received a response from API, but then this API will continue send POST request to webhook, how can i capture the response from Webhook.

```
def request_api(number)
  url = 'http://localhost:3550/call'
  @response = HTTParty.post(
    url,
    :body=> { :phone => "#{number}",
              :webhookURL => "http://localhost:3550/call"}.to_json,
    :headers => { 
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      'Authorization' => '77d22458349303990334xxxxxxxxxx'
   }
  )
  render json: @response
end
```

I can see the POST request sent by API in server.ts, and there is a status, how can i capture this status in rails.
POST http://localhost:3550/call (id=1267 status=completed) - received response code=200

Answer (score 0):

Try `render json: { status: :ok }` instead of `render json: @response` to send back a response to the API that your server has received webhook successfully. That way you can prevent API keep sending you same webhook again and again.

Use `params` to capture the response received with the webhook.

Comment: thank you so much! I successfully get the status from webhooks now but not sure how to send these data to my React frontend.

Comment: I'm not too clear about how your system works. Do you listen to webhooks coming from an external API from your rails server and then pass the payload into a react frontend?

Comment: Yes. The API will send 3 post requests to webhook url and return 3 different responses, if i render :json @response, it will only send the 1st response to frontend, I'm wondering how to send the other 2 to frontend as well.

Comment: Try saving each response on your database and create a background job to return those data to your frontend. Maybe this will work.